# C++/CLI Module Initializer for managed code

Tags: c++, c++-cli, managed, clr-module-initializer

Is it possible to run managed initialization code for a c++/cli dynamic library? 
I have a large collection of managed classes all wrapping underlying unmanaged functionality, used by many different solutions. I now need to call some managed code before anything else is executed, and I've tried several attempts but haven't been successful yet.

I initially tried running the code in the DllMain function, but quickly realized that you cannot call managed code inside DllMain, as it's not safe and LoaderLock occurs. 
I then discovered I could code my own Module Constructor like so:

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4483 )
void __clrcall __identifier(".cctor")()
{
    // Do managed code initialisation here
}
```

However, this seems to override the default Module Constructor, and I get a lot of linker warnings like:

```
warning LNK4210: .CRTMP section exists; there may be unhandled static initializers or terminators
```

Some research indicates that the default module constructor _DllMainCRTStartup calls _CRT_INIT, which initializes the the C/C++ static objects. The general consensus seems that it's a very bad idea to override the entry point for the dll, and I don't want to cause more problems for myself down the line.

The last thing I tried was creating a global static object of the managed initializer class in global scope, hoping that it may be initialized inside _CRT_INIT, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Is there ANY way I can execute some managed code as a module initialization or even execute delayed code that is still guaranteed to be called before anything else in the module?

Thanks, at the moment I am relying on providing a static initialization function that is called on an application level, but I obviously can't enforce all users of this library to do that in their applications. 
The other option I see is to add the initialization call in all managed class constructors, but again, I can't be sure anyone building on this library will follow the same design pattern, and it seems like a lot to maintain, especially if there is an easy way to do CLR module initialization.

Comment: No, the module initializer is a very, very big deal in C++/CLI.  It is required to get the CRT initialized, as well as any static native objects you may use in your managed code.  You'll have to make-do with a ref class type initializer.  You are not explaining why this is important to you so the odds for getting a usable answer are zero.

Comment: Why doesn't the constructor for a global instance of a class work? It's got to run some time before the high level entry point of your program. Do you have other global or static member objects that depend on the init?

Comment: *"at the moment I am relying on providing a static initialization function that is called on an application level"* This is exactly what you should do. *"but I obviously can't enforce all users of this library to do that in their applications"* That is not your problem. As the library vendor, your job is to document the requirement and make it relatively easy for a competent programmer to fulfill it. It is not your job to solve the problem of incorrect usage of your library. There are infinitely many ways something can be misused. Ideally, arrange for it to blow up in their face if they do so.